# HaSatan how should it be described?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, commentaries, evil-resha, evil-inclination

The Babylonian Talmud (Bava Bathra 16a) states that the Evil Inclincation (Yetzer ha-Ra), the Angel of Death and HaSatan are identical. The Talmud seems to distinguish between  HaSatan outside man (serves G-d as a sort of prosecuting attorney in the heavenly court; book of Job), and the Yetzer HaRah that exists within man. It is this evil impulse within man that allows Satan the opportunity to work his will against man.

This made me a little confused:

1) First of all what does the word satan mean (diduk)?
2) Secondly what is HaSatan and what does it do?;
Is it something intrinsic of exentric to us? or both?;
*Is HaSatan to be understood as a function, concept, title, designation or any description of something?*

Comment: 'Satan' means adversary-- Bamidbar 22:22,32; Melachim Alef 11:14,23.

Comment: The word root is ‘to prosecute’ or ‘to accuse’ which is the essential function of both. All 3 are from the side of judgment and discernment and are faithful servants of the King of the universe. An important distinction concerning this internal aspect is that it can be applied either to oneself, as in judging oneself inappropriately, or to one’s views toward others, as in judging others.

Comment: See Igerres Hamussar: https://www.sefaria.org/Ohr_Yisrael%2C_Iggeret_HaMusar?lang=en